# Matlab:how to interpolate non motonic data

Tags: arrays, matlab, interpolation

I have a question regarding the interpolation of some vectors which can not be monotonic.

The data vectors looks as follow:

```
x =        x1 =       y =
   20.0000   21.6000     32
   21.8000   19.8000    132
   22.2000   18.0000    193
   21.4000   16.6000    351
   20.2000   17.0000    576
   20.6000   16.0000    649
   20.3000   13.4000    686
   19.4000   12.2000    806
   16.9000   11.4000   1117
   15.8000   11.2000   1252
   15.6000   10.9000   1281
   15.3000    9.7000   1379
   14.8000    9.2000   1527
   14.5000    8.7000   1577
   12.4000    7.2000   1943
   11.8000    5.0000   2047
   10.4000    3.0000   2282
    5.3000    2.1000   2840
    3.5000    2.0000   3047
    2.6000    1.8000   3140
```

(small part)

I would link to achieve 'y1' as interpolation of these using:

```
y1 = interp1(x,y,x1);
```

but x and x1 are not monotonic.

y1 should be as long as y

Have you an idea of  how to perform the interpolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort both y and x such as x is monotonic. than sort x1 and use it as presented.

See if the code below helps.

```
[new_x,indx]=sort(x);
new_y=y(indx);
new_x1=sort(x1);

%solves duplicate entries through the unique function (1) or average entries (2)
[temp_new_x,indx]=unique(new_x);

% (1) discard all repeated x values except the last one
new_y=new_y(indx);
new_x=temp_new_x;

% (2) average repeated entries
new_y = arrayfun(@(C) mean(new_y(C==new_x)),temp_new_x);
new_x=temp_new_x;


y1=interp1(new_x,new_y,new_x1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used your code but I encountered two problems: the first with plot(x,y,x1,y1,'ro-'); the interpolation doesn't match but there is not the non-monotonic error. The second problem refers the full data. If i use all my data vector (those over 20 are long only) return the problem of non monotonic,perhaps because there may be some duplication.

Comment: regarding the 1st problem is because you cannot plot the raw x1. y1 is linked with new_x1 and not x1. therefore you should have plot(x,y,new_x1,y1,'ro-'). you can skip the sort of x1 and give x1 directly to the interp1, i just added this for coherency. regarding the second question check if you really have duplication and if so is it in the x or x1?

Comment: Ok i solved the "plot question" though there is a small stretch where some points do not match. Regarding the second question I have duplucation in both x and x1

Comment: @Mixo Look into `unique` to solve "duplication" errors.

Comment: @Divakar It may not be as simple as using unique. Regarding x1 duplications don’t really matter as they will not influence the interp1. However, in the x it is important and unique is not the solution. Mixo how did you obtained such data? how can you have duplicated data in x?

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro the data are some measurement and may happen to find the same value also with different y

Comment: @Mixo A simple solution, yet I do not think it is the best one is to average all y in which x is equal. This solves the duplication problem. Yet if this make sense is dependent on your data.

Comment: ...most likely I'll have to interpolate a vector with a lot of duplicate data and the solution above is not the best because I can not change the length of the vectors. Have you another solution or suggestion? Thank you so much

Comment: I have no other suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Sort the x data and re-index the y data using the results, then interpolate:

```
[sortedX, IX] = sort(x);
y1 = interp1(sortedX, y(IX), X1);
```