# matlab: interpolation vector with a lot of duplicate values

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Maybe my question might seem a little strange.

I have 3 vectors x1, y1, and x2

x1 and x2 have a lot of duplicate values, I would like to get y2 by interpolation with the same lenght of y1

```
y1 = [350 770 800 920 970 990 1020 1054 1080 1100];    

x1=[10 10 11 14 13 12 10 10 10 7]; 

x2 = [10 10 13 13 15 13 13 10 10 10];
```

(*actually have greater length, but always the same for all*)

Is it impossible or a non-sense question? (in any case, my problem would remain unsolved)

Comment: Give an example to explain what you want

Comment: @LuisMendo This question goes in the following of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935793/matlabhow-to-interpolate-non-motonic-data/23935853#23935853

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro: I'm sorry only now I read your last comment...but I hope in a resolution of my problem so I wrote a clearer example

Comment: @LuisMendo: example added to my question

Comment: If you have data that has dissimilar Y values for the same X, or could be thought of as noisy estimates of some correct Y value but with noise added to it,   it seems likely that you want to look into fitting rather than interpolation.   Polynomial fitting would likely be the place to start.

Comment: @dennis x1 refers only to Y1 Could you give me a little example. Thank you so much

Comment: Why not sorting x1 and reorder y1 accordingly and then also sort x2 and then use standard interpolation like interp1?

Comment: that is? Could you give me an example